# Multiple Commands Produce error - Xcode 15.2 Archiving

Tags: xcode, xcode15

I am new to programming, and I am building an app. As I want to upload it to TestFlight, I try to Archive it. However, when doing so, I get this error:

error: Multiple commands produce .../GoogleUtilities_Privacy.bundle'
note: Target 'GoogleUtilities-1ae1c552-GoogleUtilities_Privacy' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output .../GoogleUtilities_Privacy.bundle'
note: Target 'GoogleUtilities-54d832b6-GoogleUtilities_Privacy' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output .../GoogleUtilities_Privacy.bundle'

error: Multiple commands produce .../RCTI18nStrings.bundle'
note: Target 'React-Core-60309c9c-RCTI18nStrings' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output .../RCTI18nStrings.bundle'
note: Target 'React-Core-RCTI18nStrings' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output .../RCTI18nStrings.bundle'

I am able to build the app on the Simulator, but not Archiving it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcode%5D+multiple+commands+produce) and all of their answers. Surely your solution is in one of those.